# Need to replace blank value in CSV file with a fixed value

Tags: c#, csv

I need to read a CSV file and replace the 42nd value with a fixed field (the word "Create" in quotations).  I have a var which is the splitline im using to identify the 42nd field and replace if it is blank, but I do not know how to write the new line to a new file; the code below does not work.  Please advise,

```
using System;

using System.IO;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

 

namespace ML_ModifyCSV

{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            string filePath =

             @"C:\Test_Files\staging\OriginalFile.CSV";

            StreamReader reader = null;

            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test_Files\staging\NewCSVFile.temp");

            try

            {

                if (File.Exists(filePath))

                {

                    reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath));

                   

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)

                    {

                        writer.Flush();

                        //Upload Action is the 42nd field

                        var line = reader.ReadLine();

                        var values = line.Split(',');

                        if (values[41].Trim() == "")

                        {

                            values[41].Replace("", "\"Create\"");

 

                        }

                        writer.WriteLine(values);

 

                    }

                }

            }

            catch (System.Exception excep)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(excep.Message);

            }

            finally

            {

                writer.Flush();

                writer.Close();

            }

 

 

        }

 

    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0).

Comment: 1) Don't use emoty strings as the old value of `Replace` function. 2) use `using` blocks in  your readers and writers to safely handle the `IDisposable`s.

Comment: Can I see an example of working code?